# Given the lat long of the centre of a rectangle, how do you get the lat long of the bottom left corner of the rectangle

Tags: latitude-longitude

I have the latitude and longitude of a point. This point is in the centre of a rectangle that is 2miles wide and 8 miles long. The rectangle has an azimuth (angle from north) of 35degs. How do I get the latitude and longitude of the bottom left corner of the rectangle.

Comment: Which software are you working with?

Comment: Where on earth is it?